# how to restart and finish the program(up&down game) by entering y,n in c++

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner(c++) and i want to know how to restart up&down game by pressing y(yes) and finish by 
         pressing n(no) when you get the number right. ("would you like to play again (y or n)?")
  I tried use if when the number is same as you picked but it failed and keep showing "too low, try again" 
I know how to use number to finish the program but don't know how to use alphabet to restart and finish the program. please help this poor beginner and i would appreciate your advice.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    int random = 1 + rand() % 1000;
    cout << "I have a number between 1 and 1000."<<endl<<" Can you gess my number? "<<endl<<"Please type your first guess." << endl;
    int num = 0;

    for (;;) {
        cin >> num;
        if (num == random) {
            cout << "1. Excellent! You guessed the number!" << endl << "would you like to play again (y or n)?";



        }
        if (num < random) {

            cout << "too low. ty again" << endl;

        }
        if (num > random) {
            cout << " too high. try again" << endl;

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome t Stack Overflow! If you want help with your homework, please [edit] your question to show what you've come up with so far, and explain why it isn't working the way you expected it to.

Comment: when i put y after i get the number right, i want this program to restart so i can play again. Also i want it to finish the program after i put n.

Answer (score -1):

```
int c;
printf("would you like to play again (y or n)? ");
getchar(c);
if (c=='n') return;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this probably works, it is C-ish and won't help so much learning C++

Comment: This comment makes no sense. If you write kilometers of code for the purposes of it, this is probably not the forum.